# Pause HTML audio when particular element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I want to implement background music on a site i'm creating. Theres also a music video thats pops out when a user hits the play button. How can I pause the background music once the play button is clicked on?

**Play button html** - The play button triggers a fancybox video popup. This is when I'd like to pause the background sound below.

```
   <div class="play-btn ">
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="https://vimeo.com/1741943434" >
            <img src="../img/play-btn.svg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
```

**Audio file**

```
 <audio autoplay>
    <source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: An onclick event listener and `.pause()` on the audio element (and maybe a variable to store `isPlaying` in order to play the music back again) should do the job, but you'll have to try coding a bit yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pause() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp),

try with the following code.

```
<div class="play-btn " onclick="pauseAid()">
    <a class="fancybox-media" href="https://vimeo.com/1741943434" >
        <img src="../img/play-btn.svg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>


 <audio autoplay id="myAudio">
    <source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>

<script>
var aid = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 
function pauseAid() { 
    aid.pause(); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: This worked fine. Though the music doesn't resume once the video is closed.

Comment: for that you have to use vimeo api, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625367/fire-event-when-vimeo-video-stops-playing).

Comment: `if (aid.paused) {aid.play();} else {aid.pause();}` try this

Comment: @samsos: if this answers was helpful for you then please upvote.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <audio id="bgmusic" autoplay>
    <source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>

<script>
 $('.play-btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#bgmusic').get(0).pause(); 
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Do you have jquery included?

Comment: Have you tested it ?