# How to manage different events with event listener for different elements?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, vimeo-api

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var player_1_listener = $('#myVid_1')[0];
    $f(player_1_listener).addEvent('ready', ready);

    var player_2_listener = $('#myVid_2')[0];
    $f(player_2_listener).addEvent('ready', ready);

    function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) 
    {
        if (element.addEventListener) 
        {
            element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
        }
        else 
        {
            element.attachEvent(eventName, callback, false);
        }
    }

    function ready(player_id) 
    {
        //var froogaloop = $f(player_id);
        if (player_id === myVid_1)
        {
            var froogaloop = $f(player_id);
            function onFinish() 
            {
                froogaloop.addEvent('finish', function(data)
                {
                    /*var players_unloading;
                    players_unloading=$('#myVid_1');
                    $f(players_unloading[0]).api('unload');*/
                    toggleOverlay_1();
                    $f(froogaloop[0]).api('unload');
                });
            }
            //onFinish();
        }
        else if (player_id === myVid_2)
        {
            var froogaloop = $f(player_id);
            function onFinish() 
            {
                froogaloop.addEvent('finish', function(data)
                {
                    /*var players_unloading;
                    players_unloading=$('#myVid_1');
                    $f(players_unloading[0]).api('unload');*/
                    toggleOverlay_2();
                    $f(froogaloop[0]).api('unload');
                });
            }
            //onFinish();
        }
    }
    onFinish();
});
```

I have 2 buttons which on clicking open an iframe and play videos. I am trying to get the player within the iframe to call it's api pause method to pause the video. I can do this well if I use only one iframe video, but I am unable to do when there are multiple iframe videos.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to work with adding parameters to the functions in a way to re-use as much code as possible. The way i see it you can add playerid in all related functions and use that to minimize code within the `ready(player_id)` by utilizing the `player_id` as main id to help access all related video items.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var player = $('#myVid')[0];
 var player2 = $('#myVid2')[0];
 $f(player).addEvent('ready', ready); 
 $f(player2).addEvent('ready', ready); 

  function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
     element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    }
    else {
      element.attachEvent(eventName, callback, false);
    }
  }

  function ready(player_id) {
    var froogaloop = $f(player_id);

    function onFinish() {
      froogaloop.addEvent('finish', function(data) {
      toggleOverlay(player_id);
      resetVideo(player_id);
  });
 }
 onFinish();
}

});

function toggleOverlay(playerid){
  $("#" + playerid).parent("#specialBox").parent().css("opacity",".8");
  $("#" + playerid).parent("#specialBox").parent().toggle();
  $("#" + playerid).parent("#specialBox").toggle();
}

function resetVideo(vidID)
{
   var player;
   player=$('#' + vidID);
   $f(player[0]).api('unload');
}
```

Example using froogaloop2.js lib[old]: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/pEmEJE

Example using player.js from vimeo[new improved]: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/GNKjbe

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thank You Nasir. This solution works. One doubt - Here we are unloading the video but the annotations on the previous videos still lingers when you reopen a video. Is this a vimeo api issue?

Comment: Hmm. I am not seeing it. Can you send a screenshot?

Comment: I added the screenshot in my original question

Comment: Yes is see it. I am working on a solution. Seems to be an issue with the api unload method.

Comment: Hey Saili. I think the issue is that the unload api happens to hide the annotations if called more than once. I am still looking into it but as a quick fix you can add a css class to keep that overlay hidden: .player .outro-wrapper-in { display: none !important;}.

Comment: Also i have removed the froogaloop js and used the vimeo's own api. Here is sample of alternate code. I think this is much cleaner then the froogaloop one. http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/GNKjbe. If you want to go through the api i used check this link out https://github.com/vimeo/player.js

Comment: Fixed the hidding of related or promoted from video at end of video. Check code here :  codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/GNKjbe. Use $("div.outro-wrapper.in").hide(); in the ended event of video.

Comment: Hey @Nasir, I tried your code on the codepenIDE and its still the same issue.

Comment: @SailiG i am sorry. I have tried every possible way to removing that more from overlay. But unsuccessful. Please do check the codepen again for a much better and less re-usable code idea. Still look if can find a solution for it. codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/GNKjbe . One opiton is you can control the more videos if the videos are uploaded through your account on vimeo and you can set the embed settings of the video to not show more related videos.

Comment: Hey @Nasir, Thank you for all your efforts. I really appreciate it. I'll work around this from here on

Comment: Hey SailiG. Have fixed as much as i can. I found out another bug that was causing the video overlay to not hide sometimes after reaching end. Please review the codepen again. Now i am reloading the videos on click so that the related video section is reset. Hope this helps.