# How to make Fancybox close when Vimeo video finished?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, vimeo

### Issue

It's a relatively simple problem that I'm not able to get:

I'm using Fancybox with a Vimeo embed and trying to auto close the fancybox once the video has ended, but I'm not able to get it to close.

### Attempted Solutions

I've attempted to implement the code from this example: ([Fire event when vimeo video stops playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625367/fire-event-when-vimeo-video-stops-playing)) and by looking at the Vimeos repository on Github: (https://github.com/vimeo/player.js)

### Code

(Note: I'm attaching this to the 'afterload' event in Fancybox)

```
afterLoad: function (current, previous) {
    // Attempted Solution 1
    var iframe = $('.fancybox-iframe')[0],
        player = $(iframe);
        console.log(player);
    $(player).ready(function() {
        console.log('ready!!');
    });
    $(player).on('ended', function(data) {
        console.log('finished!!');
        $.fancybox.close();
    });

    // Attempted Solution 2
    var iframe = $('iframe .fancybox-iframe');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

    player.on('ended', function() {
        console.log('Finished.');
    });

    // Experiment 3
    vimeo : {
        color : 'red'
    }
}
```

### Results

Attempted Solution 1 works when I call `(player).ready` but nothing happens when I call `$(player).on('ended', function(data)`.

Attempted Solution 2 throws the error: "You must pass either a valid element or a valid id"

Attempted Solution 3 was just an attempt to see if I could control the Vimeo parameters by jQuery, but didn't get a result.

**Any thoughts on what I'm missing in either of these approaches?**

Comment: Vimeo docs clearly states that you have to have something like `var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);`, then it would probably work.

Comment: `Attempted Solution 2 throws the error: "You must pass either a valid element or a valid id"` - maybe that's because you passed a jQuery object instead of an actual element? Have you tried passing `iframe[0]`?

Comment: @Janis I have `var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);` listed in "Attempted Solution 2". Any other ideas?

@user7290573 I took your idea. To confirm, would it look like this: `var iframe = iframe[0];` ?